# What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $T \in L(V )$ is invertible and $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \in F$. Show that $v$ is also an eigenvector of "$T$ inverse". What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

Answer (score 4):

> Hint: If $T(v) = \lambda v$, then $v = \lambda T^{-1}(v)$

Comment: Notice that $\lambda \neq 0$, since $T$ is invertible.

Comment: You're right. Thanks (edited)